# Rotation around object using Three.js hierarchy (THREE.Group())

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have the following javascript code:

```
var group = new THREE.Group();

  var staffGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 6, 0.5);
  var staffMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
  var staffCube = new THREE.Mesh( staffGeometry, staffMaterial );
  staffCube.position.x = -21;
  staffCube.position.y = 1;
  staffCube.position.z = -19;
  group.add(staffCube);
  //scene.add( staffCube );

  var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 10, 3, 100, 16 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
  var torusKnot = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  torusKnot.position.x = -21;
  torusKnot.position.y = 4.8;
  torusKnot.position.z = -19;
  torusKnot.scale.set(0.08, 0.08, 0.08);
  group.add(torusKnot);
  //scene.add( torusKnot );

  var ballGeometry1 = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(0.5);
  var ballMaterial1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
  var ball1 = new THREE.Mesh(ballGeometry1, ballMaterial1);
  ball1.position.x = -22.5;
  ball1.position.y = 4.5;
  ball1.position.z = -20.5;

  group.add(ball1);
  //scene.add(ball1);

  var ballGeometry2 = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(0.5);
  var ballMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
  var ball2 = new THREE.Mesh(ballGeometry2, ballMaterial2);
  ball2.position.x = -22;
  ball2.position.y = 6.5;
  ball2.position.z = -20;
  group.add(ball2);
  //scene.add(ball2);

  scene.add(group);
```

The THREE.Group() was an attempt to utilize hierarchy. I can't seem to find ANY useful examples or documentation on THREE.Group so not even sure if I'm using hierarchy correctly. My goal was to set the staff in place, and make it easier to do stuff with the other components through hierarchy.

Mainly, I want ball1 and ball2 to circle around the staff. I am not sure how to access them within the group so that they can use taurusKnots location (head of staff) to translate to, rotate on taurusKnots Y, then translate back.

Any help on utilizing hierarchy with three.js to achieve this would be awesome! Like I said, all I can find online are people saying to use Group() for hierarchy, but nothing is said or can be found (by me at least) on how to access members and actually utilize the hierarchy you establish.